# fullcalendar do something when view change

Tags: javascript, view, fullcalendar, onchange

I need to do something when view change. For example when from motnh go to agendaDay.

Didnt work anythink.any ideas?

```
viewRender:(function() {

                var lastViewName;
                return function(view) {

                    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
                    alert('The new title of the view is ' + view.title);
                }
            }),
```

and

```
viewRender:(function(view) {
                var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
                alert('The new title of the view is ' + view.title);
            }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small error in the code. You want the function inside the `()` to return another function but it isn't running. The correct form is:

```
(function() {
    return function(){...};
})(); //extra parentheses run the function
```

This is called a [Self-Executing Anonymous Function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/).

---

Your code works when you do:

```
viewRender: (function () {
    var lastViewName;
    return function (view) {
        var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
        alert('The new title of the view is ' + view.title);
    }
})(),
```

Answer (score 10):

In FullCalendar 5 this seems to be `datesSet`: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet

Comment: This still works in v6 as well.

Answer (score 5):

As noted by @Willow (thanks), accepted answer will not work in version 5x.

*viewRender*, *eventAfterAllRender*, *datesRender* are all obsolete and break in version 5. Below are some [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) documentations I found listing breaking changes per release.

- ver. 4 [Upgrading from v3](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3)
- ver. 5 [Upgrading from v4](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4)

[DatesSet](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet) is the property to be used. Screenshot from ver. 5 documentation:
[image]

Taking your code example, below works for me. In case it benefits someone else.

```js
// version 5.11.0 based code
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    ...
    datesSet: function (dateInfo) {
        var view = dateInfo.view;
        alert('The new title of the view is ' + view.title);
    },
    ...
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Little late but try:

eventAfterAllRender: (function (view) {

```
// your code
```

}),

Comment: This function has been deprecated as of v4